# CSS to keep two DIVs left and right?

Tags: css

The source is:

```
<article>  

<div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden">
  <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even" property="content:encoded">

     Text at LEFT

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="field field-name-field-image field-type-image field-label-hidden">
  <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">

      <img src="right.jpg" alt="at RIGHT" />

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</article>
```

How can I change the CSS to make the two DIVs to look like?

```
+--------------+--------+
|Text at LEFT  |    ####|
|              |    ####|
|              |    ####|
|              |        |
|              |        |
+--------------+--------+
```

i.e. Text to alight top-left at left DIV, image to align top-right at right DIV.

UPDATE:

I am using something like:

```
.field-name-body {
    width: 320px;
    float: left;    
}

.field-name-field-image {
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
}
```

but I am not sure how to *protect* the above class from polluting the css global name space. I wish I can limit the `float left` and `float right` within the `article` scope...

Comment: I would use something like [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: @Hiral existing css attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/copujoribosi/1/edit)

From your DOM, you may use other Front frame. So, you should define the css to restyle the DOM. And add the following class.

```
.fr  {
  float: right;
}
.fl{
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To make text align left or right use

```
.text-left{
    text-align:left;
}
.text-right{
    text-align:right;
}
```

and to make element left or right

```
.fl{
    float:left;
}
.fr{
    float:right;
}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use `float: right` or `position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;` for the image.

Using flex:

```
article {
    display: flex;
}
.field {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 5px; margin: 5px; border: 1px solid #acacac;
}
.field img {
    float: right;
}
```

Using `display: table`:

```
article {
    display: table; 
    border-spacing: 5px; border-collapse: separate;
    width: 100%;
}
.field {
    display: table-cell; height: 100%; width: 50%;
    padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #acacac;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.field img {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```
.field-type-image
{
    float: right;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.field-type-text-with-summary
{
    float: left;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.field{ display:inline-block}

.field-type-image .field-item
{
    float: right;

}

.field-type-text-with-summary .field-item
{
    text-align:left;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `float:left` it floats the content to the leftmost part and floats to the rightmost part for `float:right`, irrespective of the width of container. So if width of container is more than width of its children, you will notice remaining gap.

Add following for right aligned content.

```
.field-name-field-image {
    text-align:right;
}
```

Following are possible solutions for it:

**Solution1:**

Float both divs to left.

```
.field-name-body, .field-name-field-image {
    float: left;
}
```

[**See DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/gtvycdeu/3/)

**Solution2**

Give proper width to the container.

```
.field-name-body {
    float: left;
}
.field-name-field-image {
    float: right;
}
article{
    width: 620px;
}
```

[**See DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/gtvycdeu/2/)

Hope it helps.